# Empty textfield produces multiple asterisks

Tags: javascript

I have this code that adds a red asterisk if a text field is left empty. I want it so that the asterisk goes away once the document detects input in said text field. I also want to prevent more asterisks getting added `IF` one is already there and text field is still empty. I have tried running `IF ELSE` statements to make it happen but get errors. Thank you for any help.

```js
const button = document.getElementById('button')
const listdiv = document.querySelector('.listdiv')
var urlinput = document.getElementById('text').value

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // Get URL and add it into a link
  let createA = document.createElement('a')
  createA.href = urlinput
  createA.textContent = urlinput

  // Get description and add it to the link
  let descrInput = document.getElementById('description').value
  let strong = document.createElement('strong')
  strong.textContent = descrInput

  if (urlinput.trim() !== '') {
    listdiv.appendChild(strong)
    listdiv.appendChild(createA)
  } else {
    var ast = document.querySelector('.ast')
    var createAst = document.createTextNode('*')
    text.style.border = '1px solid #ff0000'
    ast.style.color = '#ff0000'
    ast.appendChild(createAst)
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <title>Meine Testseite</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="formdiv">
    <form>
      <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Enter URL" id="text" autofocus>
      <div class="ast"></div>
      <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Link description" id="description">
      <input type="button" value="Add" class="button" id="button">
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="listdiv">

  </div>

  <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a personal preference, but I might turn around your `if` statements to get a better handle on the problem:

If the field is blank and if there are no asterisks already showing, then add an asterisk; (optional) else if the field is blank and there is an asterisk; else if the field is not blank.

You can get the value of the asterisk div using something like `document.querySelector('.ast').innerHTML` and then include it in your `if` statement:

```
if (urlinput.trim() === '' && document.querySelector('.ast').innerHTML === "") { 
  add an asterisk 
} else if (urlinput.trim() === '' && document.querySelector('.ast').innerHTML === "*" {
  don't add an asterisk 
} else {
  appendChild as you've already got them
}
```

The trick with this solution is that it'll really only work if there's 1 asterisk field on the page.  Based on your question, that assumption holds up.  If that's a bad assumption, let me know.

Comment: Thank you for this. That should bring me forward. For clarification, what would the code look like when you say "don't add an asterisk?" Just `return`?